# MomentJs giving NaN result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to count the days from current date to a certain date, and i'm using momentJs to do it, the problem is that it's giving me NaN result, maybe because of the date formatting!
I'm fetching the end date from an api, and it's in this format ***"DD MM YYYY" "16/12/2023"*** but in moment I don't know how it's formatted, some help would be appreciated.

The code i'm using

```
const start = moment();
  const end = moment(post.validTill);
  const diff = end.diff(start, "days");
```

I just want to get the days from current date till the end date !

Comment: On Moment.js's homepage they give examples of how to do this. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `const end = moment(post.validTill, 'DD MM YYYY');`

Comment: @GrafiCode thank you, i just used 'DD MM YYYY' and it worked, thanks again

Comment: @sultan.h glad it worked, please accept the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the duration and request the value in days.

```js
const
  diffInDays = (start, end) => moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asDays(),
  dateFormat = 'DD MM YYYY',
  nextWeek   = moment().add(1, 'weeks').format(dateFormat),
  post       = { validTill: nextWeek },
  diff       = diffInDays(moment(), moment(post.validTill, dateFormat));

console.log('Start of next week:', nextWeek);
console.log('Days until:', diff); // 6.xxx (days)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```